# Flashlight of Camera in My Universal Windows App Only Works Once

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-mobile, torch, flashlight

I am working on a Universal Windows App in Windows 10 platform. The app is supposed to use the camera to capture barcode and do something useful with the barcode. So far, it works fine with capturing and translating the barcode (using ZXing Library). I can use it to capture barcode one after another by clicking the button once for each barcode.

But I need it to work in low light situation. I want to ask the camera to automatically turn on the flashlight (or the torch) in low light situation. I find that the camera can automatically turn on the flashlight (or the torch) in low light situation *before* I take the first photo. Somehow the flashlight turns itself OFF after the first photo. I want it to stay ON as long as the user is still staying in the same page of my app (and as long as the environment is dim). Please help me to solve this problem.

So far I can determine that MediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync() is the command that turns OFF the flashlight.

The following is a working test program that demostrates this problem.

It is the MainPage.xaml program file in the test app:

```
<Page
    x:Class="TestApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TestApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
      <CaptureElement Name="captureElement"
                      Stretch="UniformToFill"
                      Margin="32,-93,34.5,181.5"
                      d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition, TopPosition, BottomPosition" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto" >
         <CaptureElement.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform Rotation="90"/>
         </CaptureElement.RenderTransform>
      </CaptureElement>
      <Button x:Name="btnCapture" Content="Capture Barcode" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,203" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="64" BorderThickness="2,2,4,4" Background="#33FFFFFF" BorderBrush="Black" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" Click="btnCapture_OnClick" Width="340"/>
      <Button x:Name="btnTerminateApp" Content="Terminate This App" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="66" Margin="10,0,10,42" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="#33FFFFFF" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2,2,4,4" FontWeight="Bold" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition" Click="btnTerminateApp_OnClick" FontSize="20"/>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

It is the MainPage.xaml.cs program file in the test app:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.Graphics.Imaging;        // For BitmapDecoder.
using Windows.Media.Capture;           // For MediaCapture.
using Windows.Media.Devices;           // For FocusSettings, FocusMode, AutoFocusRange.
using Windows.Media.MediaProperties;   // For ImageEncodingProperties.
using Windows.Media.Playback;          // For MediaPlayer.Volume.
using Windows.Storage;                 // For StorageFile.
using Windows.Storage.Streams;         // For IRandomAccessStream.
using Windows.UI.Popups;               // For MessageDialog().
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;   // For WriteableBitmap.
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
//using ZXing;                           // For BarcodeFormat.

// The Blank Page item template is documented
// at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace TestApp
   {
   /// <summary>
   /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
   /// </summary>
   public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
      {
      private MediaCapture captureMgr { get; set; }

      public MainPage()
         {
         this.InitializeComponent();
         this.InitCapture();
         }

      private void btnTerminateApp_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
         {
         this.ReleaseCapture();
         Application.Current.Exit();
         }

      private async void btnCapture_OnClick( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
         // Capture the barcode photo and translate it into a barcode number. And then
         // use the barcode number to mark the piece as checked out. 
         {
         // Capture the barcode and translate it into a barcode number.

         //....Capture the barcode photo from the camera to a storage-file.
         ImageEncodingProperties fmtImage = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();
         StorageFile storefile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync
            (
            "BarcodePhoto.jpg",
            CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName
            );
         await this.captureMgr.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync( fmtImage, storefile );

         //....Convert the barcode photo in the storage file into a writeable-bitmap.
         IRandomAccessStream stream = await storefile.OpenAsync( FileAccessMode.Read );
         BitmapDecoder decoderBmp = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync( stream );
         WriteableBitmap bmp = new WriteableBitmap( (int)decoderBmp.PixelWidth,
                                                    (int)decoderBmp.PixelHeight );
         bmp.SetSource(stream);

         //....We are done with the temporary barcode image file. Delete it.
         await storefile.DeleteAsync();

         ////....Translate the barcode photo from the writeable-bitmap into a barcode number.
         //
         //ZXing.BarcodeReader bcodeReader = new ZXing.BarcodeReader();
         //
         //BarcodeFormat[] aAllowedFormat = new BarcodeFormat[] { BarcodeFormat.CODE_39 };
         //bcodeReader.Options.PossibleFormats = aAllowedFormat;
         //   // We only want it to deal with one barcode format. Hopefully this will reduce the
         //   // chance of reading the barcode number wrong, or speed up the decoding process.
         //   // Note that this option only works if we includes "Microphone" as a required
         //   // DeviceCapability of this app in Package.appmanifest. If we don't include
         //   // "Microphone", we will get an unhandled exception here.
         //
         //bcodeReader.Options.TryHarder = true;  // Try this option to see if we can reduce the
         //                                       //    chance of failing to translate the
         //                                       //    barcode into a number. So far no problem
         //                                       //    as of 11/21/2016.
         //
         //var result = bcodeReader.Decode( bmp );
         //if ( result == null )
         //   return;
         }

      private async void InitCapture()
         // Initialize everything about MediaCapture.
         {
         this.captureMgr = new MediaCapture();
         await this.captureMgr.InitializeAsync();

         // Skip the steps to set the photo resolution to the second lowest in order
         // not to make this test program too big.

         // Start the camera preview.
         captureElement.Source = this.captureMgr;
         await this.captureMgr.StartPreviewAsync();

         // Set the camera to auto-focus.
         var settings = new FocusSettings { Mode           = FocusMode.Continuous,
                                            AutoFocusRange = AutoFocusRange.FullRange };
         await this.captureMgr.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.UnlockAsync();
         this.captureMgr.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.Configure( settings );
         await this.captureMgr.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.FocusAsync();

         // Turn on the flashlight in case the lighting is dim. Without enough
         // lighting, the auto-focus feature of the camera cannot work.
         var cameraFlashLight = this.captureMgr.VideoDeviceController.FlashControl;
         if ( cameraFlashLight.Supported )
            {
            if (cameraFlashLight.PowerSupported)
               cameraFlashLight.PowerPercent = 100;
            cameraFlashLight.Enabled = true;
            }
         // //////////////////////////
         // Tried replacing flashlight with torch. But get the same problem.
         // //////////////////////////
         //var cameraTorch = this.captureMgr.VideoDeviceController.TorchControl;
         //if ( cameraTorch.Supported )
         //   {
         //   if ( cameraTorch.PowerSupported )
         //      cameraTorch.PowerPercent = 100;
         //   cameraTorch.Enabled = true;
         //   }
         // //////////////////////////
         }

      private async void ReleaseCapture()
         {
         captureElement.Source = null;
         await this.captureMgr.StopPreviewAsync();
         this.captureMgr.Dispose();
         }
      }
   }
```

In order not to force people to install ZXing Library just to try the test app above, I have commented out everything related to ZXing Library in the test app.

The user can work around the problem by leaving that page (and back to the main menu) and then going right back to the same page. This resets something in the program and gets the auto-flashlight function to work again. Obviously this is not a good workaround because the user needs to do this for every single barcode taking. Please note that the test app shown above only has one page and doesn't have the main menu. Therefore, you won't be able to see this workaround using the test app above.

I tried to workaround this by resetting MediaCapture after taking every single photo. This is done by calling ReleaseCapture() and InitCapture() in my test app shown above.  Unfortunately this not only slows down each capture of barcode, but also this triggers a System.ObjectDisposedException about the object is not initialized or something like that. Anyway, I prefer to fix the original problem instead of using a workaround.

By the way, in my development PC, I have Windows 10 Professional and Visual Studio 2015 Professional. The Windows phone that I am using is Microsoft Lumia 640 LTE with Windows 10 Moblile version 1511 OS-Built 10.0.10586.107.

Please help me to fix this problem. Also welcome any suggestion.

Thanks in advance.

Jay Chan

Comment: Any suggestion?  Please let me know.  Thanks.

Comment: I have tried to use "Lamp" instead of flashlight or torch.  Unfortunately the Windows Phone that I am testing with doesn't support Lamp API.  Just in case someone has the same problem as I have, he may want to read this article to see if Lamp may work for you:   [link]https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/camera-independent-flashlight

Comment: I have tested your code on Lumia 640 build 1607, flash light can always work well. Please try to update your OS version to build 1607.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately upgrading to 1607 (the Anniversary update) doesn't make any difference to me.

Comment: I have changed the project target build to 1697.  Rebuild and deploy.  No difference.  One thing unusual is that when I tried to use Windows Update to update the phone to version 1607, the Windows Update didn't find any update that was available for my phone.  I got around this by using "Insider Fast" option to install "Windows 10 Technical Preview for Phone (OS Build 10.0.14393.67)" (that is version 1607).  Now I think about this, I am wondering if this phone is not meant to use version 1607. <too long and need to post the rest in the next comment>

Comment: Having said this, you said that the test app works fine in your phone.  This gives me hope.  This means I should not spend too much time fooling around with the code.  I should focus on getting the right version of Windows Phone.  May I ask you which manufacturer, model and version your Windows phone is?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like something wrong with your phone.  Settings about my test phone as follows:Model:Microsoft RM-113, Version:1607, OS build :10.0.14393.321, Hardware software number:2.1.72,Installed RAM:1GB. It should can update, if you updated to 14393, it should work. Please resolve cannot update issue firstly, after all, 14393 has came for a few time.

Comment: Hello.  Do you mean yours is Microsoft RM-1113 (with three '1') not RM-113 (with two '1')?  RM-1113 is from the Lumia 640 family.  I only find one web page that mentioned RM-113 from Indonesia, and I am not sure if that was a typo.  Just like what you said, I need to get the full version of 14393 into my phone.  That probably is the solution of this problem.  But the update cycle comes in waves, and mine probably is not available yet.  I will get a different one to try out.

Comment: For cannot update your OS version, please contact the phone support.

Comment: I have tried a new Windows 10 Phone that has Windows 10 pre-loaded (instead of upgrading it from Windows 8.1).  And I have no problem updating it to Anniversary edition (10.0.14393.576 version).  But it still has the same problem.  I plan to try a different way to solve this problem (asking the user to "tap-to-focus" in low-light environment instead of using "continuous-focus").  I will see how this goes.

Answer (score 0):

Turn out the solution is quite simple.  All I need to do is to reset the CaptureElement by releasing it first and then re-initializing it, like this:

```
this.ReleaseCapture();
this.InitCapture();
```

The tricky part of ReleaseCapture() is that I cannot Dispose the MediaCapture. Otherwise, the program will crash when I try to re-initialize the CaptureElement.  Therefore, the ReleaseCapture() is like this now:

```
private async void ReleaseCapture()
   // Release the resources used for capturing photo.
   {
   try
      {
      captureElement.Source = null;
      await this.captureMgr.StopPreviewAsync();

      //////////////
      // Don't dispose it. Otherwise, when we re-initialize it right after we have released it, the program will
      // crash. We are better off don't do this here. When we are leaving the page, the page will release it
      // anyway.
      //////////////
      //this.captureMgr.Dispose();
      /////////////////////////////
      }
   catch( Exception ex )
      {
      String sErrMsg = String.Concat( "Fail to release resources related to the ",
                                      "use of the camera. The error message is: ",
                                      ex.Message );
      await new MessageDialog( sErrMsg, "Error" ).ShowAsync();
      }
   }
```

The other things is that I need to replace the use of flash with torch when I initialize the CaptureElement. The reason is that I prefer to use the torch to have a continuous lighting. Admittedly this has nothing to do with this problem. But I mention this just to explain why this version of InitCapture() looks different from my original one:

```
private async void InitCapture()
   // Initialize everything about MediaCapture.
   {
   this.captureMgr = new MediaCapture();
   await this.captureMgr.InitializeAsync();

   // Skip the steps to set the photo resolution to simplify
   // the sample program.

   // Start the camera preview.
   captureElement.Source = this.captureMgr;
   await this.captureMgr.StartPreviewAsync();

   // Ask the camera to auto-focus now.
   var focusControl = this.captureMgr.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl;
   var settings = new FocusSettings { Mode           = FocusMode.Continuous,
                                      AutoFocusRange = AutoFocusRange.FullRange };
   focusControl.Configure( settings );
   await focusControl.FocusAsync();       // Wait for the camera to focus

   // Turn on the torch in case the lighting is dim. Without enough
   // lighting, the auto-focus feature of the camera cannot work.
   var cameraTorch = this.captureMgr.VideoDeviceController.TorchControl;
   if ( cameraTorch.Supported )
      {
      if ( cameraTorch.PowerSupported )
         cameraTorch.PowerPercent = 100;
      cameraTorch.Enabled = true;
      }

   #region Error handling
   MediaCaptureFailedEventHandler handler = (sender, e) =>
      {
       System.Threading.Tasks.Task task = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(async () =>
         {
         await new MessageDialog( "There was an error capturing the video from camera.", "Error" ).ShowAsync();
         });
      };

   this.captureMgr.Failed += handler;
   #endregion
   }
```

I have tried this in three different Windows Mobile 10 phones.  They all work.

Hope this helps someone.

Jay Chan

Comment: Somehow this method (resetting the capture-media) will cause frequent program crash if the phone doesn't have a flashlight or torch (such as Lumia 635).  Therefore, if someone wants to use this method, he needs to check if the device has flashlight or torch before resetting the capture-media.  Of course, if the device doesn't have a flashlight or torch, there is no need to use this method anyway.